# Trigger events only when Bootstrap modal is shown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, htmx

I have a webpage (Flask powered) that loads lots of modals by using a loop:

```
{% for _, product in products_table.items() %}
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modal-{{product.CODIGO}}" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ product.PRODUTO }}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table" id="product-detail">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Loja</th>
                            <th scope="col">Estoque</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for store in toy_store_list %}
                            <tr id="tr-{{ store.alias }}">
                                <td>{{ store.name }}</td>
                                <td><span style='font-weight: bold' hx-trigger="load target:#modal-{{product.CODIGO}}" hx-get="{{ url_for('product.get_product_stock', store=store.alias, search_term=product.CODIGO) }}"
                                    hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="this">
                                    <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm htmx-indicator" role="status"></div>
                                </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want HTMX to only make the GET request when ONE bootstrap modal is launched (clicked). Currently, when the page loads, it is making one request for each modal in page.

I tried using hx-trigger="load target:#modal-{{product.CODIGO}} without any good results.

Comment: How do you launch a modal? I would use the launch button's click event to trigger the HTMX request.

Comment: You could also use the modal `shown` event listener. [bootstrap-4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#events), [bootstrap-5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#events)